# Issue with PyroCMS clean URLs

Tags: codeigniter, uri, pyrocms, pyro

**What do I need to change to get my site to present the CleanURLS ?**

I installed PyroCMS with Apache Mod ReWrite option, the installation was successful, however when I click on the links I get..

http://domainname.com.au/index.php/contact

I want to get..

http://domainname.com.au/contact

If I type the URL in the address bar as http://domainname.com.au/contact  Pyro still works and supports the clean URLs however the links are being presented with the index.php. I looked into

```
\\mywebsite\system\cms\config\config.php
```

and confirmed that index_page is blank so the system should present the clean URLs unless there is another file I need to amend.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: I know Codeigniter but never used PyroCMS. Please check if the page that you access is served from cache and is it cached with index.php?

Comment: Yes you are right. Codeigniter had cached a page before I changed the config file. All resolved now

Answer (score 1):

For the record, if you select "Apache (/w mod_rewrite)" this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Force regeneration of cached query result by removing the navigation_m model cache folder
located here: `system/cms/cache/<site>/navigation_m/`

worked for me